How do I add multiple .md files to the catalog in Kedro
I have multiple .md files that I want to process. I want to add them all under a single name in catalog. But .md files isn't supported by the framework.
Example: I have multiple files on data/01_raw/folder_name/ , I want to be able to read all the .md files in there.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I suggest looking into using a PartitionedDataSet in Kedro to manage multiple Markdown files. This approach allows you to handle all files within a directory collectively. You can find more details in the Kedro documentation on PartitionedDataSet.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It worked. Here is the code that I used:
markdown_dataset:
  type: partitions.PartitionedDataset
  path: data/01_raw/md_files/
  dataset:
    type: text.TextDataset
    fs_args:
      open_args_load:
        encoding: "utf-8"
  filename_suffix: ".md"

